# Projects not appearing in Google Cloud Console / `gcloud projects list` for added Project Editor/Viewers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-console

After adding other users from my organization as Project Editor and Viewer the projects aren't showing up in their Google Cloud Console project list, nor are they visible in `gcloud projects list`.

However if I give them a link directly to some resource inside the project they can navigate to it just fine,
and they can also use commands like `gcloud container clusters list` with the `--project=` set to the new projects and see the resources inside the project.

The documentation for the `gcloud projects list` (https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#listing_projects) specifies it should list all projects on which you have `resourcemanager.projects.list` (which Project Viewer and Editor both grant) or any children under a parent on which you have `resourcemanager.projects.list`.
So maybe if I grant `resourcemanager.projects.list` on the organization level it would fix it, but I don't really want to grant the users such a broad access...

Comment: In order for a user to list projects in an organization, they need `resourcemanager.projects.list` at the organization or folder level. What concerns do you have with this permission? If a user has access to a project, allowing them to list projects should not be an issue unless revealing the names of projects is not desired. In that case, just provide everyone with the Project ID and they can manually use that to access resources.

Comment: Note: The level (project, folder, organization) determines what users can access. You could create folders, move projects under folders and allow users to only list projects in their folders.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by John Hanley :

> In order for a user to list projects in an organization, they need resourcemanager.projects.list at the organization or folder level.If a user has access to a project, allowing them to list projects should not be an issue unless revealing the names of projects is not desired. In that case, just provide everyone with the Project ID and they can manually use that to access resources.

> Note: The level (project, folder, organization) determines what users can access. You could create folders, move projects under folders and allow users to only list projects in their folders

For more information you can refer to the [Serverfault Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1062924/667978) related to a similar issue and  [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders)  where creation and management of the Folders has been well explained.

> Here is how to replicate:
>
> 1. As an admin create a "newProject990055" under an existing organization, select it and navigate to the IAM menu.
> 2. Add a user with just the role "Logs Viewer" for "newProject990055".
> 3. Login with such a user and try to select project "newProject990055". Expected: User won't see "newProject990055"
>    because the user has no access to list all projects, and
>    "newProject990055" is new, and the user has never visited it before.
> 4. With such a user hit https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query?project=newProject990055.
>    Expected: User will see the logs for the "newProject990055" project
>    and user will be notice that such a project is selected.
> 5. Logoff and login back with such a user, click on the dropdown for projects. Expected: User should be able to see project
>    "newProject990055"  because even though the user has no access to list
>    all projects, and "newProject990055" is new, the user has already
>    visited it before.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to this question specifically but it did give the same problem of project lists not being populated. I'll put it here in case it helps someone (I ended up on this question when trying to figure it out).

Basically my projects list wouldn't populate because I had a plugin for CORS added to my browser for development. When I disabled the plugin the list populated. (It gave some other strange problems in google products - images wouldn't load on google sheets).